# Javah command for native methods gives Exception

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

I entered this into command prompt and I'm not sure why it is saying that it is not a valid class name considering that it has the position on the disk and the fully qualified class name. Java - version works and I'm running the latest version of the JVM with the JDK, also the CLASSPATH is configured properly.

The class is this:

```
package JNI;

public class Main {

public native void printTitle();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.print();
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("The print subroutine has finished.");
}
```

And the command line args are:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNI Test Project\build\classes\JNI>javah -jni -classpath "C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNI Test Project\build\classes\JNI" JNI.Main.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: JNI.Main.class
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:177)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:68)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:509)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:335)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Comment: Viewed 10,594 times, please open this question!

Comment: I am having this problem javah -jni -classpath "\home\npsdk\niagara_dev_home\sampl
es\npsdkJni\npsdkJni-rt\src\" -d "\home\npsdk\niagara_dev_home\samples\npsdkJni\npsdkJni-rt\src\native\npsdk\include\jni\" com.tridium.nre.NreLinuxNpsdk0
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.tridium.nre.NreLinuxNpsdk0'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`classpath` should point to the root folder where your top level package (JNI) goes to, not to the folder where your class is physically located.

Class name should not include `.class` extension.

Think about it as operating on classes and not physical files.

`javah -jni -classpath "C:\Users\GETH COMMANDER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNI Test Project\build\classes" JNI.Main`

Also you should follow Java naming conventions and make your package names lower case.

Comment: Confused about the reason why this thread is closed, I'm the "future visitors" and I got help from this thread. ^_^